# Email form not posting all fields in PHP

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I'm trying to write a simple form for a site of mine, it doesn't need to be super secure etc but for some reason its only posting the last input data "Enquiry", can anybody see what I may be doing wrong?

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="form-process.php" name="form" class="form">
    <label>Company Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="Company">
    <label>Your Name (required)</label>
    <input type="text" name="Name">
    <label>Your Email (required)</label>
    <input type="text" name="Email">
    <label>Your Message</label>
    <textarea name="Enquiry"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button radius" />
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

if ( empty($_POST['Company'])) {

    echo '<span style="color:#ff0000; font-weight:700; font-size:12px;">Please ensure all fields marked with an asterisk(*) have been completed.</span>';

} else {

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value);

    $message = '';

    $message .= htmlentities($key)." - ".htmlentities($value)."\r\n";

    $headers = 'From: me@websites.co.uk' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: me@website.co.uk';

    if(mail('liam@myemail.co.uk', 'Enquiry', $message, $headers)){ 

        echo '<span style="color:green; font-weight:700; font-size:12px;">Thank you, we will be in touch within 24 hours.</span>';

    } else {

        echo '<span style="color:#ff0000; font-weight:700; font-size:12px;">Sorry, your message wasn\'t sent, please try again.</span>';

    };

};

?>
```

Comment: You should place the following code: `$message = '';` out of `foreach`.

Comment: because you are resetting value of `$message` every time. Write `$message = '';` before foreach.

Comment: There is no reason to use `htmlentities()` on `$key`. It's something you contro, not user input

Answer (score 4):

Your `foreach` statement seems to be wrong.

The actions that PHP should perform 'for each' array element, should be enclosed by curly braces. So instead of

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value);

$message = '';
$message .= htmlentities($key)." - ".htmlentities($value)."\r\n";
```

you should use:

```
$message = '';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $message .= htmlentities($key)." - ".htmlentities($value)."\r\n";
}
```

And yes - it might sometimes work without curly braces. However, I'd strongly suggest to be consistent and *always* use curly braces, to prevent bugs like these from sneeking into your code. It also makes your code easier to read (in my personal opinion).

As you can see, I also moved `$message = ''` outside of the foreach statement, because you only want to set `$message` to be an empty string *before* you start filling it with data - otherwise you reset `$message` every time before you add some new data.

Comment: These two are actually equivalent. It's weird, I know, but it works. "A semicolon ends the statement and a foreach statement is similar to a function - it opens up a scope"

Answer (score 3):

Try below:

```
$message = '';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
    $message .= htmlentities($key)." - ".htmlentities($value)."\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are set message to empty string each time

```
$message = '';
```

You should do it only once before the loop.

Also your foreach loop is incorrect. You put ";" in the end. But you need to put code inside "{}"